# Unable to search archived Outlook email through Excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, outlook, office-automation

I have created macro to search outlook latest email with specific subject name & then forward it with pasting some range from Excel into body of email & the code is working fine for recent email. but not working for archived emails. While I search old emails, I get a "Type Mismatch" error.

This is the code:

```
Sub Online_Email()
  Dim outlookApp As Variant
  Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
  Dim Fldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
  Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
  Dim olFMail As Outlook.MailItem
  Dim myTasks As Variant
  Dim sir() As String
  Dim rng As Range
Dim wb As Workbook
  Dim obwb As Workbook
  'Set outlookApp = New Outlook.Application
  Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

  Set olNs = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set Fldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
  Set myTasks = Fldr.Items
  
  
For Each wb In Workbooks
If wb.Name Like "Consolidated observation file*.xlsb" Then

Set obwb = wb

obwb.Activate
Exit For
End If
Next

  
  
  lastrow = obwb.Sheets("Daily Observation").Range("F50000").End(xlUp).Row
  Set rng = obwb.Sheets("Daily Observation").Range(Cells(8, 1), Cells(lastrow, 6)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
  
  '
  'Set olMail = myTasks.Find("[Subject] = ""123456""")
  '
  For Each olMail In myTasks
  '
    If (InStr(1, olMail.Subject, "Consolidated Observations", vbTextCompare) > 0) Then
      Set olFMail = olMail.Forward
           With olFMail
           .To = "Pravin.Angane@eclerx.com;Jaysing.Pardeshi@eclerx.com;Suhas.Bhange@eclerx.com;Dadasaheb.Kamble@eclerx.com"
           .CC = "Jaysing.Pardeshi@eclerx.com;Suhas.Bhange@eclerx.com"
           .HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>" & obwb.Sheets("AutoMail").Range("a1") & "<br><br>" & obwb.Sheets("AutoMail").Range("a2") & "</BODY></HTML>" & RangetoHTML(rng) & olFMail.HTMLBody
           .Subject = obwb.Sheets("AutoMail").Range("i3")
           End With
           Set Myattachments = olFMail.Attachments
 
        While Myattachments.Count > 0
 
         Myattachments.Remove 1
 
         Wend
        olFMail.Attachments.Add "\\IPSAABACUS\CM_Shared$\SalesForce\Jyoti Sahay\VA-Training\Scrubbing feedback\Observations\Consolidated observation file - Oct-2022.rar"
        
           
        
          olFMail.Display
      Exit For
    End If
  Next




    'Dim outForward As Outlook.MailItem
    
    'Set outForward = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1).Forward
    'outForward.Recipients.Add "pravin.angane@eclerx.com"
    'outForward.Save


End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
    Dim obj As Object
    Dim txtstr As Object
    Dim File As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    File = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"
    rng.Copy
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With wb.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    With wb.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=File, _
         Sheet:=wb.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=wb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With
    Set obj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set txtstr = obj.GetFile(File).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = txtstr.readall
    txtstr.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")
    wb.Close savechanges:=False
    Kill File
    Set txtstr = Nothing
    Set obj = Nothing
    Set wb = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: *where* specifically do you see that error?

Comment: Hard to diagnose your problem without know the exact line on which you get the error as per @TimWilliams comment, but my money is on you having non-`MailItem` items in your inbox and so the error appears on either the `For Each olMail In myTasks` line or the `Next` line ... if this is the case, a fairly simple answer can be provided (but I don't have space enough to put it here in a comment)!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to keep in mind that Outlook folders may contain differnet kind of items - appointments, notes, mails and etc. So, when you loop over all items in the code it makes sense to iterate using object and check its type with  the [MessageClass](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.messageclass) property or just use the following code:

```
If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
```

Second, iterating over all items in the folder is not really a good idea. Use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods to get items that correspond to your conditions. Read more about these methods in the articles I wrote for the technical blog:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)